# Haskell - Incrementation fails

Tags: list, haskell, auto-increment

I'm in a big trouble with incrementation of a counter in this code. It doesn't increment.
**Edit:** It works now fine!

Could you please tell me where the problem ist and how can I solve it?

```
replaceBasedIdx    ::  String  ->  [String]  ->  String  ->  String
replaceBasedIdx    findStr replaceStrList myText = replaceBasedIdxSub findStr replaceStrList myText 0

replaceBasedIdxSub  ::  String  ->  [String]  ->  String  -> Int -> String
replaceBasedIdxSub findStr replaceStrList myText counter = loop myText 0
  where
    loop [] _ = []
    loop myText counter =
      let (prefix, rest) = splitAt n myText
      in
        if findStr == prefix                                -- found an occurrence?
        then (replaceStrList !! counter) ++ loop rest (counter+1)   -- yes: replace it

        else head myText : loop (tail myText) counter              -- no: keep looking
    n = length findStr
```

**Incrementation works just fine in this code**

Why is this so?

```
numStack :: [Integer]
numStack = [20, 45, 150, 85, 19, 31, 50, 74, 57]

sumStack :: Integer
sumStack = sumStackSub 0

sumStackSub :: Int -> Integer
sumStackSub counter = if (counter < (length numStack)) then
                            sumStackSub (counter + 1) + (numStack !! counter)
                         else
                            0   -- dummy value
```

Thank you very mutch!

Greetings!

Comment: Are you aware that `counter` is immutable?  Are you aware `counter + 1` will return a value and not mutate `counter`?

Comment: thanks for your response! so how could I increment the counter?

Comment: in my other code it works s. my question update please!

Comment: In your update you are not mutating counter but creating a new value and performing a recursive call.

Comment: I need a counter which increments, could you pleas tell me, how I achive it easyly in my new code also? Please help me, it's very importent for me THANKS!!!

Comment: No, you don't need a counter that increments, you need to pass the counter as an argument to `loop`.

Comment: Thanks to all, actualy I recognized it after the hint of Thomas M. DuBuisson, however I couldn't post the update earlier - sorry about that!

Comment: one stepp is though left yet: I must write one more function, which does the following: `replaceBasedIdxMultiple ["A","X","G"] ["N","Y","K"]  "ABXMG"`.
Output: "NBYMK"    - so how can I modify my replaceBasedIdxSub, in order to have the result as in this example shown? Should I use `map`. but how?

Comment: @John I think you should create a new question for that.

Comment: ok, I'll do it. Thanks for the notice

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in the comments, you can't mutate `counter`, but you can call `loop` with an incremented value of `counter` as parameter:

```
replaceBasedIdx    ::  String  ->  [String]  ->  String  ->  String
replaceBasedIdx    findStr replaceStrList myText = replaceBasedIdxSub findStr replaceStrList myText 0

replaceBasedIdxSub  ::  String  ->  [String]  ->  String  -> Int -> String
replaceBasedIdxSub findStr replaceStrList myText counter = loop myText counter
  where
    loop [] _ = []
    loop myText c =
      let (prefix, rest) = splitAt n myText
      in
        if findStr == prefix                                -- found an occurrence?
        then (replaceStrList !! (counter+1)) ++ loop rest (counter+1)   -- yes: replace it

        else head myText : loop (tail myText) (counter+1)              -- no: keep looking
    n = length findStr
```

Your second example works, because you do just that, you pass an incremeted value of `counter` to the called function `sumStackSub`.